# django reverse foreignkey lookup

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am a Django dev and I’m stuck with a problem of reverse foreignkey lookup. The problem is described as follows:

I am working on query optimization. I have a model `MicroMessage` which has a foreignkey to `User` (from `django.contrib.auth.models`) as `author`. Also there are some other classes which have also foreignkey to `User` (e.g `UserProfile`).

I need a query which will fetch author of `MicroMessage` as well as all users related to any other model from which I can access the `UserProfile` info of that author without any excessive queries. I tried this:

```
MicroMessage.objects.select_reverse({'authors':'author_set'})
```

Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, welcome to SO! can you show us the code of the models: `MicroMessage` and `User` ?

Comment: can you show a sample of code that you are trying to optimize ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for select_related
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

```
messages = MicroMessage.objects.select_related('author', 'author__userprofile')
```

The second field (a user's profile) is a reverse foreign key but if implemented as a `OneToOneField` as the docs suggest, can be queried in the manner shown above if the class was named `UserProfile`.